# Can't connect to phpmyadmin mariadb windows 10 laravel sail

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm having trouble connecting to my MariaDB database via my Laravel Sail docker environment through PHPmyadmin on Windows 10. Here's my docker compose file, what am I missing:

```yaml
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
            # - redis
            - mailpit
            - phpmyadmin
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    # redis:
    #     image: 'redis:alpine'
    #     ports:
    #         - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
    #     volumes:
    #         - 'sail-redis:/data'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    #     healthcheck:
    #         test:
    #             - CMD
    #             - redis-cli
    #             - ping
    #         retries: 3
    #         timeout: 5s
    mailpit:
        image: 'axllent/mailpit:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        networks:
            - sail
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mariadb:
        driver: local
    # sail-redis:
    #     driver: local
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 error messages below the text fields in your screenshot are telling you that it can't resolve the server name `mysql`.

In phpadmin, you need to use the service name of the database as the server name.

So instead of `mysql` as you've used in your screenshot, you need to use `mariadb`.

Also be aware that if a database already exists in the directory you've mapped to `/var/lib/mysql`, then the variables you set for username, password etc. are *not* used. Those are only used if no database exists when the container starts.

Answer (score -1):

add a link to the container. phpmyadmin needs to be linked to the running database container:

```
phpmyadmin:
  links:
    - mariadb:db
```

Comment: Still get the same error.

Comment: be sure to rebuild containers with *--build*. It can also happen that old data remains inside the container and deleting the volume and creating it again solves the problem.

`1. docker rm -f $(docker ps -qa)`
`2. docker volume ls`
`3. docker volume rm volumeName`
`4. docker compose up --build `